# Crypto API CSR process

Tags: c++, ssl, winapi, cryptography

I want to request a certificate from my own CA. I know how to create a CSR (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382364(v=vs.85).aspx) and send it, but, assuming that the server responds with a certificate, how do I "join" the two certificates to one?

I could use IE to do it for me but my users will not even know how to open IE in Windows 10 and, besides, our root certificate must be installed as well, I have to create a local application.

I checked the certificate enrollment API but I do not know how to setup my PHP app to be compatible with it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Did you not see I am asking about using the crypto api or the certificate enrollment api?